# Get Product Addon information trough get_post_meta()

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im triying to retrieve the addon label (WooCommerce Product Addon) for a custom view, Im getting the serialize array from the DB with get_post_meta() but the unserialize() outputs bool(false).

```
    $ProductMeta = get_post_meta($ParentProductID);
    $addons = $ProductMeta['_product_addons'];
    echo var_dump($addons);
```

The result from the code above is

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(530) "a:1:{i:0;a:16:{s:4:"name";s:6:"Extras";s:12:"title_format";s:5:"label";s:18:"description_enable";i:0;s:11:"description";s:0:"";s:4:"type";s:8:"checkbox";s:7:"display";s:11:"radiobutton";s:8:"position";i:0;s:8:"required";i:0;s:12:"restrictions";i:0;s:17:"restrictions_type";s:8:"any_text";s:12:"adjust_price";i:0;s:10:"price_type";s:8:"flat_fee";s:5:"price";s:0:"";s:3:"min";d:0;s:3:"max";d:0;s:7:"options";a:1:{i:0;a:4:{s:5:"label";s:14:"Add Prosciutto";s:5:"price";s:1:"3";s:5:"image";s:0:"";s:10:"price_type";s:8:"flat_fee";}}}}"
}
```

Then I tried the unserialize() function as follows:

```
    $ProductMeta = get_post_meta($ParentProductID);
    $addons = $ProductMeta['_product_addons'];
    $addons = unserialize($addons);
    echo var_dump($addons);
```

And the result for that is:

```
bool(false)
```

Comment: The returned value was an array with one element but you tried to unserialize the whole array, you need to target the element like this unserialize($addons[0]).

Comment: @Buttered_Toast thank you, that's it. How can I mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: I will create an answer and you can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned value was an array with one element but you tried to unserialize the whole array, you need to target the element like this unserialize($addons[0])